# Weight of the commentaries in the source code

Tags: application-development, programming, source-code

When I search for source-code of Linux parts (applications, kernels, ...), I often find commentaries to clarify the code.

Now, I know that those commentaries are useful to help a human reading the code, but I was wondering about the impact they have on the machine.

The commentaries aren't read by the machine, but I'm assuming the machine must at least read the first character of the line to know if it needs to read it or not :

> Machine - "Does this line start with a # ? Yes, OK, moving on ! Uh, another line, does this one start with a # ? No !! AHA, let's read that mo******er !"

So, my question is :

- Do the commentaries in the source-code slow down the machine (in a significant way, like 0,01% or more) ?

PS : maybe the builder which reads the code doesn't include the commentaries in the final program ?

Comment: You maybe want to ask at [programmers.se].

Comment: Sorry about the off-topic thing. I have an acceptable answer from Roadmr (thanks to him). Should I ask anyway on Stack-Exchange and delete this thread, or do I leave this one as it and move on ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mention the kernel as a program of concern. The kernel, and everything written in C, is compiled, so the source code is read and translated into machine code. All comments are stripped during this process. So you don't need to worry about any slowdown in comments.

Interpreted code, in, say, shell or python, could potentially suffer from comment-induced slowdown. But I'm certain it would be negligible. Comments are processed when parsing the program, at which point they would be stripped, thus they would affect the initial parsing time but not execution time.

Here's more on that topic:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731022/do-comments-slow-down-an-interpreted-language

So the bottom line is, you don't really need to worry about this slowing down things in any perceptible or relevant way.